# How to compute the norm of a complex number under square root?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to compute the norm of a complex number under square root? Does the square of norm equal the norm of square:

> $\|\sqrt z\|^2 = \|\sqrt {z^2}\|$?

Let $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $$\|\sqrt z\|^2 =\|\sqrt {re^{i\theta}}\|^2 =
\|\sqrt r \sqrt {e^{i\theta}}\|^2 =\|\sqrt r  {e^{1/2i\theta}}\|^2 =  \|r  {e^{i\theta}}\|.$$
And
$$\|\sqrt {z^2}\|=\|\sqrt {(re^{i\theta})^2}\| = \|\sqrt {r^2e^{2i\theta}}\|=  \|{re^{i\theta}}\|.$$

I hope this is correct? Thank you.

Comment: $\sqrt z$ is ambiguous notation.

Comment: er...? I meant the most common one, like $\sqrt{1 + 2i}$ @PedroTamaroff

Comment: Your calculations make no sense:  the norm of a complex number is always a nonnegative real value.

Comment: Oh sorry @heropup, I meant to keep the norm. Thanks!

Comment: @1LiterTears There is no such thing as "the most common" squareroot of a complex number!

Comment: So what are the ambiguity @PedroTamaroff? I guess one is $\sqrt z := \sqrt{|z|} e^{\frac12 i \arg z}$, right? How about the other one? Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

We claim that, for any $w \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $$\|z^w\| = \|z\|^w.$$  Proof:  if $\|z\| = 0$, then $z = 0$ and the desired condition is trivially satisfied.  So suppose $\|z\| > 0$.  Then $$\|z^w\| = \|r^w e^{iw\theta}\| = \|r^w\|\|e^{iw\theta}\| = \|r^w\| = \|r\|^w,$$ since $r > 0$.  Also, $$\|z\|^w = \|r e^{i\theta}\|^w = \|r\|^w \|e^{i\theta}\|^w = \|r\|^w 1^w = \|r\|^w.$$  So they are equivalent, even if $z^w$ is multivalued.

Comment: The definition of $z^\omega$ must be watched upon. This is where you lose generality.

Comment: It doesn't matter:  the magnitude of $z^w$ for any real $w$ is the same **regardless of the branch chosen**.  $z^w = \exp(w \log z) = \exp(w \log |z| + i w \arg(z) + 2\pi i w k)$, and the magnitude is clearly $|z|^w$.

Comment: Still you can't _define_ $z^\omega$ without _choice_ of a branch.

Comment: Of course you can.  $z^w$ is a **set** that corresponds to a relation on $\mathbb C^2$.  Nowhere is it required that such relations are single-valued, and certainly not for the purposes of this identity.  You don't need to force a choice of branch, and especially not to uniquely define the norm, which as I have pointed out, is unique regardless of branch.

Comment: You should add that to your original answer (that $z^\omega$ need not necessarily be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C$).

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. $|e^{i\theta}|=1 \quad \forall \theta\in\mathbb R$. Thus
$$\Vert \sqrt z \Vert^2 = \Vert \sqrt r e^{i\frac\theta2} \Vert^2 = \Vert \sqrt r \Vert^2 = (\sqrt r)^2 = r$$
Where $r\ge 0$ by convention.
Note that $\sqrt z$ needs clarification. The usual definition excludes a line from $0$ to $\infty$, normally either $(-\infty, 0)$ or $(0, i\infty)$ then
$$\sqrt z := \sqrt{|z|} e^{\frac12 i \arg z}$$

---

**With regards to the edit**:
Still you have the problem of defining the square root in the complex plane. If you chose a suitable definition, which limits you to a certain domain, equality will hold whenever $z$ and $z^2$ are in the domain of your square root.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot. May I first ask - how can I deal with the simple case $\sqrt{1+i}$?

Comment: $(1+i)^2 = 2i$, so taking the square root to be
$$\sqrt{\cdot} : \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0) \to \mathbb C$$
Allows to write $|(1+i)^2| = 2 = {\sqrt 2}^2 = |1+i|^2$

Comment: Sorry for unclear - I am actually concerned about the case $\|\sqrt{1+i}\|$..?

Comment: In this case, the same definition of the square root will help you find
$$\Vert \sqrt{1+i} \Vert = \sqrt[4]2$$

Comment: Oh, you mean use $\sqrt z := \sqrt{|z|} e^{\frac12 i \arg z}$, so that $\sqrt {1+i} = \sqrt{|1+i|} e^{\frac12 i \arg \frac \pi 2} = \sqrt{2} e^{\arg \frac \pi 4}$, so the norm is $\sqrt[4]{2}$? :)

Comment: A small error: $\arg (1+i) = \frac\pi2 \neq \arg \frac\pi2$

Comment: oh yes, thanks!!!

Comment: Happy to help. If this solved the question, please mark it as answered. If not, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Thank you - give me a brief second to recognize the contradiction...

Comment: Oh, since $\|\sqrt{z^2}\| = \|\sqrt{r^2 e^{2i\theta}}\|= \|\sqrt{r^2} \sqrt{ e^{2i\theta}}\| =r $, so it is true except the line needs to be excluded?

Comment: @1LiterTears You can chose which line, though, so you might as well say that depending on $z$ you chose a branch of the square root (a line to exclude) such that $z,z^2 \in {\rm dom}(\sqrt\cdot)$ and you get a general "yes".

Comment: May I ask why you want to exclude the line..?

Comment: Because of the definition of the $\arg$-function. It's only continuous (and analytic, etc.) if you remove the line at which it makes a "jump". if $\arg(-1-i\epsilon) \approx -\pi$ and $\arg(-1+i\epsilon) \approx \pi$, there's no way to define $\arg(-1)$ continuously.

Comment: Er.... why arg($-1$) can't be defined continuously....?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12686/discussion-between-alexr-and-1litertears)